# Laravel get only one column from relation

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, relation

I have a table user_childrens whose contains id_parent and id_user.
I'm trying to list all childrens of the parent with this:

code:

```
//relation in model via belongsTo
    $idparent = auth('api')->user()->id;
    $list = UserChildren::where('id_parent',$idparent)
        ->with('child:id,name,email')
        ->get();

    return $list->toJson();
```

The return is:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "id_parent": 1,
        "id_user": 1,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "child": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Mr. Davin Conroy Sr.",
            "email": "prempel@example.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "id_parent": 1,
        "id_user": 2,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "child": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Krystel Lehner",
            "email": "cernser@example.net"
        }
    }
]
```

But it's API so I want only the child column like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Mr. Davin Conroy Sr.",
        "email": "prempel@example.com"

    },
    {..}
]
```

UserChildren Model:

```
public function child() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','id_user','id');
}
```

I know that I could do this via .map() on collection but maybe there is other solution already on this query

Comment: can you show UserChildren model

Comment: ok, added @Davit

Comment: I update my answer try it and ask about result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code

```
$idparent = auth('api')->user()->id;
$childs = User::whereHas('user_childrens', function ($query) use ($idparent) {
    $query->where('id_parent', $idparent);
})->get(['id', 'name', 'email']);

dd($childs->toJson());
```

And User model define `user_childrens` relation.

```
public function user_childrens()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserChildren','id_user','id');
}
```

See also docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence